# MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using the following generator: https://github.com/diegohaz/rest

Link: [Project Github](https://github.com/Angelk90/api.store)

When I try to enter a user using the `MASTER_KEY` message I get the following error:

> MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

A similar problem I also get with the findOne:

> Unhandled rejection MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

I have tried all the proposed solutions I found here which have a similar problem, delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall `mongoose`.

Can anyone help me out?

If you want to test it there is above the link of the project.

Comment: Linking to code usually leads to a question with no value to future visitors.  External links are convenient, but putting enough code in the question to reproduce the problem will be very helpful to future visitors.

Comment: Facing the same issue. No luck!  tried whitelisting IP and creating cluster again

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error and get it solved by changing the node version while connecting and restarting the server.
I changed the default node version to "2.2.12 or later"
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0V4M.png)   and then it worked.